# Open a page and fill inputs with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

Is it possible to use a bookmarklet to open a page then autofill some information on it?
For instance [this](http://webchat.esper.net) site, then fill in all of the text with my info and check the checkbox.
Is this achievable? If so can you please provide an example?

Comment: If the site you link to does it, then yes, it is possible.

Comment: The work computer I use blocks autofill, so I was wondering if you could achieve this with the bookmarklet itself.

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Comment: You could also use something like [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) to have it fill in the form for you.